# How to do data field update based on value in a another field inside the SQL statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following table where I used to manage passwords to login.
Loging Table fields : 
UserID, EmailAddress, PassWord, LoginAttempts, LastLoginDate, LoginStatus

In my login logic,

```
1. If login password matches : 
   1. I update LastLoginDate field with the current date and time
   2. Update LoginAttempts = 0

2. If the EmailAddress (login user name) is correct but PassWord is wrong :
   1. I increment LogginAttempts by 1 
   2. If LoginAttempts > 5 then update LoginStatus = "LOCKED"

3. No need to update anything if EmailAddress is wrong
```

Currently I read the table with the following query :

```
string Query = @"SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT(user_role.USER_ROLE_ROLE SEPARATOR ',') AS ROLES " + 
                                        "FROM login " + 
                                        "INNER JOIN user_role ON " +  
                                            "user_role.USER_ROLE_USER_ID = login.LOGIN_USER_ID AND login.LOGIN_EMAIL = @Parameter1";
```

Then I compare the fields for correct PassWord and update the table with following SQL query :

```
                        Query = @"UPDATE login SET " +
                                          "LOGIN_ACCOUNT_STATUS = @Parameter2," +
                                          "LOGIN_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = @Parameter3," +
                                          "LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_DATE = @Parameter4," +
                                          "LOGIN_LAST_LOGIN_LOCATION = @Parameter5 " +
                                          "WHERE LOGIN_EMAIL=@Parameter1";
```

This is implemented externally (comparing values outside of SQL) and working fine. But I am sure this is possible to implement within SQL statement.
Could someone help me with the SQL query need to implement?
I want to see how I could merge SELECT and UPDATE into one SQL field with comparisons within SQL query if possible. I am just trying to make the code elegant. My C# function is currently 100 lines of code and could be reduced significantly if the whole thing is implemented in SQL.

Thanks,
PG

Comment: you could write this as a stored procedure, yes. Have you tried anything so far? Please show us your current code and what problem you're experiencing with it. That's normally how the site works - we fix bugs, rather than provide complete code samples (unless it's something very small)

Comment: Yes, things are written in a stored procedure. I updated my current SQL queries.

Comment: I can't see a stored procedure here, just a couple of separate queries, and no sign of any logic. Have you started to write a procedure yet? Like I said we're not here to do the whole thing for you, we'll help you fix specific issues though. You won't be able to do all that logic in one line of SQL, you'll need a procedure. Or maybe it'd be simpler to optimise the c#. Since we can't see it, it's hard to know.

Comment: I read about the Stored procedure and I learned that I am not using a one. I call the above SQL functions and do my logic.